# Find the maximum and mean length of the consecutive "TRUE"-arguments

Tags: r, string-length

I started with a daily time series of wind speeds. I wanted to examine of the mean and maximum number of consecutive days under a certain threshold change between two periods of time. This is how far I've come: I subsetted the data to rows with values beneath the threshold and identified consecutive days.

I now have a data frame that looks like this:

```
dates   consecutive_days
1970-03-25  NA
1970-04-09  TRUE
1970-04-10  TRUE
1970-04-11  TRUE
1970-04-12  TRUE
1970-04-15  FALSE
1970-05-08  TRUE
1970-05-09  TRUE
1970-05-13  FALSE
```

What I want to do next is to find the maximum and mean length of the consecutive "TRUE"-arguments. (which in this case would be: maximum=4; mean=3).

Comment: What is expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: I started with a daily time series of wind speeds. I wanted to examine of the mean and maximum number of consecutive days under a certain threshold change between two periods of time. This is how far I've come: I subsetted the data to rows with values beneath the threshold and identified consecutive days. Now all I have left to do is to find the maximum and mean length of the "TRUE"-arguments...

Comment: your example data will give the same value for both max and mean, so not sure it illustrates your problem very clearly.

Comment: Yeah , I mean this is just a little sample of my data. I will edit the sample. But did you get my problem? And do you konw how to solve it?

Comment: No. This would be my final result. So if a formula or something would just return  one value for maximum and mean length, each. That would be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `rle`:

```
# construct sample data.frame:
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(days=1:12, consec=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 12, replace=T))

# get rle object
consec <- rle(df$consec)

# max consecutive values
max(consec$lengths[consec$values==TRUE])
# mean consecutive values
mean(consec$lengths[consec$values==TRUE])
```

Quoting from `?rle`, `rle`

> Compute[s] the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector

We save the results and then subset to consecutive TRUE observations to calculate the mean and max.

You could easily combine this into a function, or simply concatenate the results above:

```
myResults <- c("max"=max(consec$lengths[consec$values==TRUE]), 
               "mean"= mean(consec$lengths[consec$values==TRUE]))
```